How to make Socket.io work from cloud IDEs workspaces? (CodeSandbox, CodeSpaces, etc)
I have a standard Node / Express / Socket.io boilerplate which doesn't work properly on StackBlitz, CodeSandbox and CodeSpaces, but works well on Replit.
To clarify, doesn't work - means Socket.io client from another domain can't connect to it.
Turns out it is because all those Cloud IDEs are using weird redirect / sign-in setup when exposing workspace URL to public - i.e. they aren't "curlable" from terminal, except for Replit.
So I'm wondering - is it possible to fix this somehow by some options in Socket.io? I've tried various CORS settings - but no avail.
Here is my boilerplate code:
import { createServer } from "http";
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {origin: '*'}
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send ("Test");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("event", { a: 1, b: "qwe", c: true });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server running at 3000");
});


Partial solution - it works from CodeSpaces as well, but you need to make port explicitly public by right clicking it in port inspector. Looking for similar solutions in 2 remaining IDEs now...
